# Who is the goddess Ahoi worshipped on Ahoi Ashtami?

Tags: identification-request, goddess, devi, festivals, children

Today is **[Ahoi Ashtami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahoi_Ashtami)** in northern India in which women keep fasts for their children's well-being just like they do for their husbands on Karva-chauth. While they break the fast on Karva-chauth after seeing the moon on Ahoi or 'Hoi' as it is locally called they break the fast after seeing the evening star.

The detailed stories and rituals can be read in this **[Drikpanchang page](https://www.drikpanchang.com/festivals/ahoi-ashtami/info/ahoi-ashtami-puja-vidhi.html)** but I am more concerned with the identification of the Goddess Ahoi. She seems to be similar to Goddess Shashthi in the sense that she is worshipped for keeping children healthy but the latter is associated with the 6th day not 8th and am not sure if they are the same.

So my question is - **Do any scriptures mention the story or give clues to the identity of Goddess Ahoi who is worshiped on Ahoi Ashtami?**

Comment: She is like Santoshi mata, some virtual Devi creation in North India, nothing is mentioned about her or Santoshi Mata in real Devi Bhagwat Purana or Shakta Sect

Comment: Only Devi's 10 forms established in 51 Shakti Peethas all over Ind-Pakistan-Nepal are mentioned in all Shakta Sects https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahavidya just like Trimurti are 3 and Adityas are 12. Not even Vaishno Devi is mentioned :/

Comment: every Shakti peetha has a Shiva lingam, so total 51 Shakti and 51 Shiva Peethas(from parts of Sati). Total 102 peetha, and rest 6 Peethas are 2in Vishnu Loka, 2 in Brahma Loka and 2 in Kailash and hence total 102+6= 108 Shiva-Shakti Peethas

Comment: I don't know why @user16678 called Ahoīmātā similar to Santoṣī and a virtual creation, the former's pūjā is being done since generations. There is a properly laid out ritual including vratakathā too, accompanied with her pūjā. There are many grāmadevatās, etc., you can't discount and call all of them fake and virtual creations, like the fake Santoṣī.